# Joining 2 objects doesn't make them 1 mesh

Tags: 3d, blender

I'm having an issue where I join 2 objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and when i'm actually sculpting the newly formed object it's like there is a line between main object and the joined object where I'm not able to sculpt

Answer (score 0):

After joining go to edit mode Mesh-Cleanup-Merge by distance.. Joining don't merge vertices. Or merge objects with Boolean modifier and choose union and apply..